# Parallel Execution in TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, access-modifiers

I trying to make a test design using **Selenium** and **TestNG**, I put each **@Test** in a separate class, and using once **@BeforeSuite** & **@AfterSuite** for all classes, the reason is:

1. The code is easy to maintain
2. Data Driven, in order to be able to choose which classes to run through the **`xml`** file.

Then what I think is how I only login once and the session can be used by all subsequent tests, what I've done so far is:

**Base** class:

```
public class Base {
    protected static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void setup() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/.../chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

**LoginApps** class:

```
public class LoginApps extends Base{
    @Test(groups= {"logintest"})
    @Parameters({"data"})
    public void loginApps(String data) {
        driver.get("https://TheUrl.com/");
        //some code here
    }
}
```

**Case1** class:

```
public class Case1 extends Base{
    @Test(dependsOnGroups= {"logintest"})
    @Parameters({"data"})
    public void case1(String data) {
        driver.get("https://TheUrl.com/");
        //some code here
    }
}
```

**Note** : The above code fine work if it is run with single **`<test>`** in suite.

The problem is if it is run parallel like the following **`xml`** configuration.

**testng.xml**:

```
<suite name="SuiteTest" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
    <test name="Test1">
        <parameter name="data" value="data1"></parameter>
        <classes>  
            <class name="com.main.LoginApps"/>
            <class name="com.main.Case1"/>
            .....
            More class
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test2">
        <parameter name="data" value="data2"></parameter>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.main.LoginApps"/>
            <class name="com.main.Case1"/>
            .....
            More class
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

The code runs by creating `driver` instance just once, and the both **`<test>`** runs overlapping in the same session. I think this is because of the way I declare `driver` as `static` in the **Base** class. But if I remove the `static`, it will make matters worse, still creating `driver` instance just once and the code only run the first **`@Test`** (in this case only **LoginApps**), all subsequent tests will get a *`NullPointerException`* exception.

I use **TestNG** v7.0.0 with **Maven** :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

To run the design that I imagined in parallel, how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Create driver with thread safety to ensure both times driver session is unique.

```
public class ThreadLocalDriver {

    private static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> threadLocalDriver = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public synchronized static void setTLDriver(WebDriver driver) {
        threadLocalDriver.set(driver);
    }

    public synchronized static WebDriver getTLDriver() {
        return threadLocalDriver.get();
    }
}

public class BaseClass {
    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup (String deviceName, String platformVersion) throws IOException {
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        // Add caps here    
        ThreadLocalDriver.setTLDriver(new ChromeDriver(caps));
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public synchronized void teardown(){
        ThreadLocalDriver.getTLDriver().quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: From **LoginApps** or **Case1** class, how to access the `driver`?

Comment: `threadLocalDriver.set / get` are already synchronized.